# In Kushiel's Avatar, How Exactly did Phedre Learn the Name of God?

Tags: jacqueline-carey, kushiel

From what I can remember, the monk she learned it from was mute. How then, did she know how to pronounce the name?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apoorv020 had it right. It was NOT explained. It was supernatural.

> Silence filled the Holiest of Holies.
>
> No stir, no echo, no whisper ofsound.
>
> Even the flames stood silent and motionless in the golden lamp-stands.
>
> And in the deafening silence . . .
>
> Tongueless and unvoiced, the priest spoke the unpronounceable
>
> Name of God.
>
> "***_*__*_*____**!"

Answer (score 2):

There was something supernatural going on there. Don't exactly remember what it was, but I think that the mute monk opens his mouth and while Phedre hears the Name of God, nobody else hears anything.